# Capitalize the first letter of word

Tags: java

Suppose i have a string value i.e michael . What i need that i want the this value in the form of 'Michael' . What could be the better programming approach though i'm beginner of java. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: initialize your string as Michael???

Comment: Here is the greatest programming help tool ever created: google.com  learn to use it and you will go far.

Comment: Thanx to everyone who have commented . Google is excellent engine but i wanted the best results from  u all :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not gonna give you the code but you can achieve what you want using the steps below:

- Get the first charcter from the string using [**String#charAt(0)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)
- Use [**Character#toUpperCas**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29)e to convert it into uppercase
- concatenate the result back to the original string

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "abcd";
Character first = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0));
str = first + str.substring(1, str.length());
System.out.println(str);  //Will print Abcd
```

This code

- Gets the first `Character` from the `String`
- Converts it to upper case (using `Character.toUpperCase(char ch)`)
- Concatenate the first letter (that was changed to upper case) with the rest of the `String`

*I don't like to use the `+` operator for concatenating strings, consider using `concat` method (or StringBuilder in case you want to concatenate more strings..)*

Comment: NP :) Make sure you understand each part of the code.